# Remove specific string and all number and blank string from array in python

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I want to remove some words and all string that contains number from this array and

```
reviews = ['', 'alternative', ' ', 'transcript', ' ', 'alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive', ' ', 'confidence', ' 0', '987629', ' ', 'transcript', ' ', 'alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive yeah', ' ', 'transcript', ' ', 'alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive life', ' ', 'final', ' True', '']

for review in reviews:
    if review == '' or review == ' ' or review == 'alternative' or review == 'transcript' or review.replace(' ', '').isdigit() or review.isdigit():
        reviews.remove(review)

print(reviews)
```

but I am not getting expected output from the array, it's output showing number and the word as well.
['alternative', 'transcript', 'alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive', 'confidence', '987629', 'transcript', 'alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive yeah', 'transcript', 'alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive I', 'm Alive life', 'final', ' True']

I cannot not understand what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you remove an element from list in a for loop, the iterator will not work as you want.

If you want to remove elements inplace, you can use `while` maybe:

```py
i = 0
while i < len(reviews):
    review = reviews[i]
    if review == '' or review == ' ' or review == 'alternative' or review == 'transcript' or review.replace(' ', '').isdigit() or review.isdigit():
        reviews.remove(review)
    else:
        i += 1
```